# Is there a way to build a Google Spreadsheet with multiple dropdowns to return data from another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to find a way to return a list of items based on responses to multiple dropdowns. For example, if you were to select from three separate dropdowns that you were on Team Alpha, based in Cincinnati, and a Manager it would return a list of items that would populate as 1 item in each cell in 1 column.

[image: Example of Description]

Comment: Maybe include pictures to make your explanation clearer? It's kind of confusing...

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy uploaded. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: the question is too broad to answer but its possible

Comment: Any sample data?

Comment: I have upvoted your question for changing it. You deserve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`query()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) will be helpful. In your case, assuming the original data is on `data` sheet, you can use query like this:

```
=query(data!A:D, "select A where B = '"&A1&"' and C = '"&B1&"' and D = '"&C1&"'")
```

Sample spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12X6TbVOip8a7rp3uGzodWSLcu6hONm3SPVltROauMLY/).